# VSFTP Error Connecting

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, filezilla

I am running Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 LTS with VESTA CP installed.

I can connect via ftp without any problems while I am on my LAN using the server's local ip address. However, when I try to connect via my public IP, I can't (I am using Apple's Airport Express as my router and am allowing ports 21 and 1200-12100 to access the server).

Here is my vsftpd.conf:

```
 anonymous_enable=NO
 local_enable=YES
 write_enable=YES
 local_umask=002
 anon_upload_enable=NO
 dirmessage_enable=YES
 xferlog_enable=YES
 connect_from_port_20=YES
 xferlog_std_format=YES
 dual_log_enable=YES
 chroot_local_user=YES
 listen=YES
 pam_service_name=vsftpd
 userlist_enable=NO
 tcp_wrappers=YES
 force_dot_files=YES
 ascii_upload_enable=YES
 ascii_download_enable=YES
 #allow_writable_chroot=YES
 allow_writeable_chroot=YES
 seccomp_sandbox=NO
 pasv_enable=YES
 pasv_max_port=12100
 pasv_min_port=12000
 #pasv_address=2*.*.*.* (public ip)
```

Here is the message I receive from FileZilla.

[image: FileZilla Connection Message!]

What can I do in order to connect using my public ip?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after racking my brain and eyes reading tons of information, I found the solution. I just needed to tell FileZilla to connect via SFTP (port 22) instead of FTP (port 21).

Now everything works perfectly.